# How to skip Lombok getters and setters while calculating test case coverage in Eclipse?

Tags: java

I am using Lombok for generating getters and setters for the beans.
But I want to exclude these methods (getters and setters) while calculating the test case coverage in Eclipse.

How can I do that?

Comment: What plug-in or tool do you use to calculate the test case coverage in Eclipse? Add that information to the question text!

Comment: @Lii can u pls help me on this ?

Comment: @Lii I am not using any tool. I am just using JUnit.

Comment: Is there any configuration change that I need to do in eclipse ?

Comment: junit doesn't come with a coverage tool, it's just a testing API and doesn't have anything to do with your IDE. An Eclipse plugin is providing test coverage, most likely EclEmma. Navigate to Help > About Eclipse Platform > Plug-in Details and confirm if you're using EclEmma.

Comment: why do you want to exclude? you want to write custom getters and setters?

Comment: @Deadpool I assume he doesn't want to include getters and setters in test coverage because if they're auto-generated there is no point testing them and he doesn't want the lack of coverage to reflect in the metrics. Personally, I'd just be fine with the coverage report, it's just another metric, no need to have 100% and indeed with 100% it's no proof the code is doing what it's intended to.

Comment: @Robert yes I am using EclEmma for test cases coverage.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using EclEmma. From the [user guide](https://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/preferences.html) you can exclude classes and classloaders but not methods.

> Excludes: A list of class names that should be excluded from execution analysis. The list entries are separated by a colon (:) and may use wildcard characters (* and ?). (Default: empty)
>
> Exclude classloaders: A list of class loader names that should be excluded from execution analysis. The list entries are separated by a colon (:) and may use wildcard characters (* and ?). This option might be required in case of special frameworks that conflict with JaCoCo code instrumentation, in particular class loaders that do not have access to the Java runtime classes. (Default: sun.reflect.DelegatingClassLoader)